# Getting different values inside vs. outside a function while using global array

Tags: programming

function `splitter` is designed to get a string of parameters and create a an array of parameters. If only part of parameters were given, the rest of them will get default values.

for example : input string `1,2,3,4` would fill `parameters` array with values `{"1","2","3","4"}`, but  if input string is `1,2`, `parameters={"1","2","20","0"}` while `parameters[3]` and `parameters[2]` were given its default values.

**BUT**

when assigning default values, inside `splitter` the correct values are stored in `parameters` but when using `print_output` function to show `parameters` values - different values are shown.

in output supplied, when input is `1,2`,  default values should be pasted, to `parameters[2]`, and `parameters[3]` , while input is `1,2,3,4` no need to use defaults.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Running string 1,2
param_2 was set to default value:20
param_3 was set to default value:0
output:
1
2
0
0
Running string 1,2,3,4
output:
1
2
3
4
```

**CODE:**

```
#define PARAM_AMOUNT 4
#define COLOR 1
#define LED_DELAY 20
#define BRIGHTNESS  50
#define LED_DIRECTION 0


char *parameters[PARAM_AMOUNT] = {"0", "0", "0", "0"};
int param_def[] = {COLOR, BRIGHTNESS, LED_DELAY, LED_DIRECTION};


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Running string 1,2");
  splitter("1,2");
  print_output();

  Serial.println("Running string 1,2,3,4");
  splitter("1,2,3,4");
  print_output();
}


void splitter(char *inputstr) {
  char * pch;
  int i = 0;

  pch = strtok (inputstr, " ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    parameters[i] = pch;
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    i++;
  }

  //  update default values
  for (int n = i ; n <= PARAM_AMOUNT - 1; n++) {
    sprintf(parameters[n], "%d", param_def[n]);
    Serial.print("param_");
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.print(" was set to default value:");
    Serial.println(parameters[n]);
    delay(50);
  }
}

void print_output() {
  Serial.println("output:");
  for (int n = 0 ; n <= PARAM_AMOUNT - 1; n++) {
    Serial.println(parameters[n]);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: not an error, but strange `n <= PARAM_AMOUNT - 1`. write `n < PARAM_AMOUNT`

Comment: Create a 2-dimensional array that has enough bytes or use an array with pointers so you can set the pointers to default strings. You have now a mix of those two and it is not well defined. At least write in comments what the maximum values are (how many decimal digits).

Comment: @jot - you are write for not commenting, but each parameter in range [0,100]. integer only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to reserve memory for a string with a constant string. Allocate an array of char arrays with:

```
char parameters[PARAM_AMOUNT][PARAM_LEN];
```

Now with "0" you allocate 2 bytes for each string. The '0' and a terminating 0.

Then in `splitter` function you write 3 bytes into one of the parameters with value "20". This writes outside of the 2 bytes of memory reserved for the string.

`strcpy(parameters[i], pch);` will copy the token returned by `strtok` into your array. `pch` points into `inputstr` and the delimiters in `inputstr` are replaced by 'strtok' with zeros

Comment: Thank you. But but when `parameters` is not a pointer array, it can't get `pch` value... ( I guess I'm still newbie here :( )

Comment: `paramaters[i]=pch;` was changed to `sprintf(parameters[i],"%s",pch);` now all is OK